# Why the html password field getting empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

I am creating a password field where user can either hide/show the password he is entering. Below are the html and javascript code. The issue is when I am testing the code in browser:-
 I enter the password and click on 'show/hide' button and the password is visible and the page get refreshed then the password is gone. How should I solve this?

**html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Page Title </title>
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
        <input id="loginPwdChange" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <button onclick="changePwdView()"> Show/Hide </button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit"> Login </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
let loginPwdStatus = false;

function changePwdView(){

    let getLoginInput = document.getElementById("loginPwdChange");

    if(loginPwdStatus === false){
        getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
        loginPwdStatus = true;

    }else if(loginPwdStatus === true){
        getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "password");
        loginPwdStatus = false;

    }

}
```

[image: Check the image]

Comment: Apart type="button", you can replace all your if/then/else block by a single line : getLoginInput.type = getLoginInput.type === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text';

Comment: @BlackCat Do you need to submit your form back to the server?

Comment: For the time being, I dont need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your button to show / hide the password is submitting the form. When clicking the show / hide button, you need to **prevent** the form from submitting.

Two possible solutions:

**With HTML only**

---

Change your button to `type="button"`. It will prevent the form from submitting.

```js
let loginPwdStatus = false;

function changePwdView() {

  let getLoginInput = document.getElementById("loginPwdChange");

  if (loginPwdStatus === false) {
    getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    loginPwdStatus = true;

  } else if (loginPwdStatus === true) {
    getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "password");
    loginPwdStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Page Title </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
    <input id="loginPwdChange" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="button" onclick="changePwdView()"> Show/Hide </button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit"> Login </button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**With JavaScript**

---

You can do this with `preventDefault()`.

Mind the following things:

- Pass the parameter `event` to your function when clicking the button: `onclick="changePwdView(event)"`
- Don't forget the argument in your JS code: `function changePwdView(event) { ... }`
- To prevent the form from submitting, use `event.preventDefault();`

```js
let loginPwdStatus = false;

function changePwdView(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let getLoginInput = document.getElementById("loginPwdChange");

  if (loginPwdStatus === false) {
    getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    loginPwdStatus = true;

  } else if (loginPwdStatus === true) {
    getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "password");
    loginPwdStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Page Title </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
    <input id="loginPwdChange" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <button onclick="changePwdView(event)"> Show/Hide </button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit"> Login </button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your button tag to `type="button"`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Page Title </title>
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
        <input id="loginPwdChange" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <button onclick="changePwdView()"> Show/Hide </button>
        <button type="button" name="submit"> Login </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then you can add the handler to call ajax on `Login` button click

Answer (score 0):

add type="button" to the show/hide button;

```js
let loginPwdStatus = false;

function changePwdView(){

    let getLoginInput = document.getElementById("loginPwdChange");

    if(loginPwdStatus === false){
        getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
        loginPwdStatus = true;

    }else if(loginPwdStatus === true){
        getLoginInput.setAttribute("type", "password");
        loginPwdStatus = false;

    }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Page Title </title>
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
        <input id="loginPwdChange" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <button onclick="changePwdView()" type="button"> Show/Hide </button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit"> Login </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="button" onclick="changePwdView()"> Show/Hide </button>` can help

Cheers